# How to execute .click() code when previous click binding finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a Twitter Bootstrap button group with `data-toggle="buttons-radio"` in my site. Bootstrap markup as follows.

```
<div class="btn-group program-status" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button class="btn">All</button>
    <button class="btn">Active</button>
    <button class="btn">Planning</button>
    <button class="btn">End of Life</button>
    <button class="btn">Cancelled</button>
</div>
```

I need to redirect to the same page with query depending on the pressed button. I tried to use following jQuery code to achieve this.

```
<script>
    var sParamStr = '';

    function addToParamStr(str) {
        sParamStr += str;
    }

    function redirectToUpdatedLocation() { 

        $('.program-status > .btn.active').each(function () {
            addToParamStr( '?status=' + $(this).text());
        });

        console.log(sParamStr);
        window.location.href = "program" + sParamStr;
    }

    $document.ready(function () {
        $('.program-status > .btn').on('click', function (e) {
            redirectToUpdatedLocation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But the browser always redirects to {site}/program without the query string. By commenting out `window.location.href = "program" + sParamStr;` line, I managed to observe that second click onwards, `sParamStr` getting appended properly.

It seems that, my code tries to read the text of the pressed button before, `.button('toggle')` method form bootstrap.js finished. Code worked as intended when I changed function as follows.

```
$document.ready(function () {
    $( '.program-status > .btn').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        redirectToUpdatedLocation();
    });
});
```

While this method works for me right now, I would like to know the proper way to achieve this. i.e How to execute my code after previous click binding finishes?

UPDATE:

I found this link in the Twitter Bootstrap forum. Seems it is a known issue.
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2380

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Bootstrap's `.toggle` is doing exactly, but it seems like it does some sort of animation that completes with the setting of the `active` class.  You can try enqueing your code instead:

```
$( '.program-status > .btn').on('click', function (e){
    $(this).queue(function (next) {
        redirectToUpdatedLocation();
        next();
    });
});
```

For example, click the div as it is being toggled: http://jsfiddle.net/9HwYy/

---

It also seems a bit silly to me to update *every* `href` instead of just the one you clicked on since you are changing the window location anyway.

Comment: My bad it was not .toggle() but .button('toggle') method. It toggles `active` class in clicked bootstrap buttons. I'll check your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.program-status > .btn.active').each(function(i,v){
  v = $(v);
  addToParamStr( '?status=' + v.text());
});
```

since im not sure "this" is working in your case.